# Log4Net Logging Variables

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, log4net-appender

Is it possible for log4net to log custom variables, or am I limited to the ["pre-configured" variables](http://www.beefycode.com/post/log4net-tutorial-pt-4-layouts-and-patterns.aspx)? e.g.

> - %appdomain: the friendly name of the appdomain from which the log entry was made
> - %date:  the local datetime when the log entry was made
> - %exception: a formatted form of the exception object in the log entry, if the entry contains an exception; otherwise, this format
>     expression adds nothing to the log entry
> - etc

I need to log session information, from `ActionExecutedContext` for example. if that's relevant I call log4net from a Global Exception filter.

Is it possible, if so, how?

The currently configured appender, using only aforementioned "pre-configured" variables:

```
<appender name="ADONetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <connectionType value="LALALA DELETED" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
      </parameter>
    </appender>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In log4net a layout can contain many patterns, ie. classes that can output one specific information when encountering their string declaration in the layout.

For example `%logger` in the layout will resolve to the `LoggerPatternConverter` class, which outputs the logger name when encountered.

There is a global instantation of all the available patterns in the `PatternLayout` class:

```
PatternLayout.s_globalRulesRegistry = new Hashtable(45);
PatternLayout.s_globalRulesRegistry.Add("literal", typeof(LiteralPatternConverter));
PatternLayout.s_globalRulesRegistry.Add("newline", typeof(NewLinePatternConverter));
PatternLayout.s_globalRulesRegistry.Add("n", typeof(NewLinePatternConverter));
PatternLayout.s_globalRulesRegistry.Add("c", typeof(LoggerPatternConverter));
```

but you can add some custom patterns to your layout through the configuration. Just create your own pattern layout converter:

```
public class ZoinxPatternlayoutConverter: PatternLayoutConverter
{
    protected override void Convert(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        writer.Write("Zoinx at {0:d}", DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

And add it to your layout:

```
<appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%message %zoinx %newline" />
    <converter>
      <name value="zoinx"/>
      <type value="App.ZoinxPatternLayoutConverter, App" />
    </converter>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Of course in your case this may be a bit much and you would perhaps benefit from deriving from a Layout directly if you only ever use one property in each layout, such as the `RawTimeStampLayout` you have in your config. Alternatively you could inherit the PatternLayout to register all the patterns you're interested in once and for all and use them across your configuration.

Comment: I kind of gave up and shoved everything into the "Message" column, but I still really appreciate the reply.